# Create a new column as SUM of two row's elements IF today's cost is less/greater

Tags: r

I have a data frame with days, costs and some variables to sum in a new column. For example:

```
    days      cost    b    c    d
1 01/12/2006  3378    75   75   80    
2 04/12/2006  3390    18   23   22    
3 05/12/2006  3346    53   53   57    
4 06/12/2006  3390    86   87   93    
5 07/12/2006  3363    67   67   77    
6 08/12/2006  3382    78   80   84
```

I would like to create a new column "new" which shows the the sum of +b and -d if today cost is greater or equal than two days ago OR the sum of -b and +d if today cost is less than two days ago:

"new" = (+b-d, if today cost >= two days ago)or(-b+d, if today cost < two days ago)

```
    days      cost    b    c    d    new
1 01/12/2006  3378    75   75   80    NA (#we don't have past days)
2 04/12/2006  3390    18   23   22    NA
3 05/12/2006  3346    53   53   57    4  (#since 3346<3378,-53+57= 4)
4 06/12/2006  3390    86   87   93    -7 (#since 3390=3309,86-93= -7)
5 07/12/2006  3363    67   67   77    -10(#since 3363>3346,67-77=-10)
6 08/12/2006  3382    78   80   84    6  (#since 3382<3390,-78+84= 6)
```

Can anyone help me with the code? I have  a very large data to analyse.

Comment: You should clarify if "two days ago" means calendar days or something else, because in your desired output for day `05/12/2006` you take cost value of day `01/12/2006` which is not two days.

Comment: I forgot an important feature: the weekend is not included.Therefore the "two days " are the two days i have in the column "days", or even better the two rows back. Sorry for the missing.

Answer (score 4):

Using `data.table` (or `dplyr`) you could do

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, New := ifelse(cost >= shift(cost, 2L), b - d, d - b)]
df
#          days cost  b  c  d New
# 1: 01/12/2006 3378 75 75 80  NA
# 2: 04/12/2006 3390 18 23 22  NA
# 3: 05/12/2006 3346 53 53 57   4
# 4: 06/12/2006 3390 86 87 93  -7
# 5: 07/12/2006 3363 67 67 77 -10
# 6: 08/12/2006 3382 78 80 84   6
```

Or using indexing

```
setDT(df)[, New := c(-1, 1)[(cost >= shift(cost, 2L)) + 1L] * (b - d)]
```

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(New = ifelse(cost >= lag(cost, 2L), b - d, d - b))
```

Or using good old base

```
transform(df, New = ifelse(cost >= c(rep(NA, 2L), head(cost, -2L)), b - d, d - b))
```

---

It would be probably better to convert `days` to a `Date` class using `df[, days := as.IDate(days, "%d/%m/%Y")]` too so you could order by it.

Comment: Wouldn't `shift` take 2 rows back and not 2 days as intended in the answer?

Comment: @danas.zuokas no. Look at `setDT(df)[, .(cost, shift(cost, 2L))]` and see OPs calculations they illustrated in comments

Comment: Could you David please explain briefly the behavior of `shift`? Now that I read help page for this function it mentions `period` for the second argument. Does this function intended only for time ordered data tables. If so how does it know which column is time variable? Could it also be unordered by time?

Comment: @danas.zuokas it has nothing to do with ordered or not. It just removes the first or the last N values and concatinates `N` NAs to the other end. Similar to  `c(rep(NA, 2L), head(x, -2L))` or `c(tail(x, -2L), rep(NA, 2L))` in base R. Or similar to `dplyr`s `lag` and `lead` functions. There is no time variable. You just specify the lags/leads in the `n` argument.